# Cannot perfectly center an element

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I am having trouble perfectly centering a div with a dynamic size that changes depending on the dimensions of the image the user has uploaded. The function is supposed to position the div absolutely in the center of the screen over all of the other content, however it is off by a small percentage regardless of the image I use... See below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df6fR.jpg

Here is the css:

```
.prompt_background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    -moz-opacity:.50; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
    opacity:.50;
    display: none;
}

.prompt_box {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

.prompt_content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

And the way with which I load it is this:

```
function showprompt() {
$('.prompt_box')
    .css("margin-left", -(($('.prompt_box').width())/2)+"px") //Horizontal center
    .css("margin-top", -(($('.prompt_box').height())/2)+"px"); //Vertical center

$('.prompt_background')
    .css('height', $(document).height())
    .css("width", $(document).width()); //Background stretch

$('.prompt_background')
    .css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=50)'); //Background opacity
$('.prompt_background, .prompt_box')
    .fadeIn(500); //Animation
}
```

As for the HTML, it's just three empty divs which I load content into via ajax

```
<div class="prompt_background">
</div>
<div class="prompt_box">
    <div class="prompt_content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/ Chris Coyer does a full walkthrough on how to do this. I would give this a read.

Comment: That's the method I'm already using, unfortunately... For some reason it still isn't perfectly centered. Maybe there's a stray margin somewhere.

Comment: Make sure to put margin:0px; padding: 0px; also remove the htc call take some pieces out at a time to see if you made a mistake, are you using firebug?

Comment: I did it, it works http://jsfiddle.net/ne6MD/ I think you might be putting to much thought into this, keep it simple.